# Checking for "nested" null attributes in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null, boolean, defensive-programming

I've got a simple method that checks there are no `null` in attributes:

```
public boolean isValid(){
     return session.getX() != null && session.getX().getY() != null &&
     session.getX().getY().getZ() != null;
}
```

This works, but, Is there any way to do this in a more elegant way?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: [Avoiding != null statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements)

Comment: it looks like codesmell and violation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check chains of "get" calls for null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458451/check-chains-of-get-calls-for-null)

Comment: With a field, the responsibility of not letting it be null follows.

Answer (score 1):

> This works, but, Is there any way to do this in a more elegant way?

With a utility class which performs reflection to retrieve the nested fields and do the check, it may be more elegant but it is surely less safe and slower:

```
public boolean isValid(){
     return NullAnalyser.isNotNull(session, "x.y.z");
}
```

Another idea would be to return a special type that allows to avoid NPE in the getter. But it makes them more complex. Is it desirable ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @davidxxx. I was thinking in reflection as well, but I'd like to get an existing library, if possible, in order to avoid "reinventing the wheel"

Comment: You are welcome. BeanUtils should do the job. For example `BeanUtils.getProperty(session, "x.y.z");` https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html

Answer (score 1):

This way is elegant if you are using java 8:

```
public boolean isValid(){
     return Optional.of(session)
                    .map(x -> x.getX())
                    .map(x -> x.getY())
                    .map(x -> x.getZ())
                    .isPresent());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to what Dimitry said if you are using Java 8 and have control over Session, X, Y and Z then you can change the signatures to return Optionals.

You can also use method references instead of lambdas which are arguably easier to read.

```
public boolean isValid(){
     return Optional.of(session)
                    .map(Session::getX)
                    .map(X::getY)
                    .map(Y::getZ)
                    .isPresent());
}
```

Comment: Yes, references are good but we don't know actual class names from the question, moreover you should remove "()" in all maps to avoid compile error.