# Handle Chained Method Calls avoiding NullPointerException - Which is the best way?

Tags: java

## Handle Chained Method Calls avoiding NullPointerException - Which is the best way?

Let's imagine this kind of scenario:
3 class `Meeting`, `Room`,  `Projector`

A Meeting might have set a Room and it might have a Projector inside them.

Now suppose that I want to know what is the model of the Projector.
The most natural thing is to do something like

```
Meeting meeting = someMethod();
return meeting.getRoom().getProjector().getModelName();
```

This code could return the model name of the Projector correctly,
unfortunately this code could also cause an Exeption: an `java.lang.NullPointerException` in case that one of the class contained into the root class Meeting (or even the Meeting class) is null.

In order to prevent this problem, and get a **default value** in the worst case we should check the returned value of each call.

```
Meeting meeting = someMethod();
if (meeting != null) {
    Room room = meeting.getRoom();
    if (room != null) {
        Projector projector = room.getProjector();
        if (projector != null) {
            return projector.getModelName;
        }
    }
}
return "No Projector Exist";
```

The code now is pretty nasty.

What is the best way to deal with this kind of chained method calls avoiding the NullPointerException?

Comment: You can find the answer in the following question. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458451/check-chains-of-get-calls-for-null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458451/check-chains-of-get-calls-for-null)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html):

```
return Optional.ofNullable(someMethod())
    .map(Meeting::getRoom)
    .map(Room::getProjector)
    .map(Projector::getModelName)
    .orElse("No Projector Exist");
```

---

As an aside, consider returning `Optional` or `null` from your method - having to compare your `String` to the special hardcoded value to detect the `null` case is going to get tiresome...

Answer (score 1):

Checking all the null conditions in one if statement also can be done as follows.
So that the code will be much easier to read.

```
    if (meeting != null && meeting.getRoom() != null && meeting.getRoom().getProjector() != null) {
        return meeting.getRoom().getProjector().getModelName();
    } else {
        return "No Projector Exist";
    }
```

The best way is to move the null checks to a private method. So when you give a meeting object, it do the required checks and return the model of the project as a string. So your code will be much simpler and with less complex.

Answer (score -3):

You can `catch()` the `NullPointerException` or throw a `NoRoomException` and a `NoProjectorException` from your `getRoom()` and `getProjector()` methods and catch those.