# Best way to check null for each part of an experssion in java

Tags: java, null, expression

So I have something that looks like this:

```
(String) loginResponse.getGroup().getAdditionalProperties().get(something);
```

and each and every component of the expression could return null. I want to avoid throwing an exception and checking if null after each call doesn't look like the best way to do it:

```
   temp= loginResponse.getGroup();
   if(temp!=null){
      temp= temp.getAdditionalProperties()
      if(temp!=null){
         temp.get(something)
      }
   }etc...
```

What's a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You didn't check if `loginResponse` is null :-P

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check chains of "get" calls for null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458451/check-chains-of-get-calls-for-null) (check the most voted answer)

Comment: yes, thank you! Apparently I couldn't find that on my own ^^'

Comment: Wow, whoever flagged this as duplicate to another question that has no actual solution really did a bad job. Thanx but no thanx.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "Optional" and chain the call inside a map()

```
Optional.ofNullable(toto).map(A::getB).map(B::getC).orElseThrow(...)
Optional.ofNullable(toto).map(A::getB).map(B::getC).orElseGet(...)
```

You avoid nullPointerException by this way. It goes in the orElse... if anly element is null at any places