# Add debug method into a method chain

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've recently started programming using Java and spring-boot, and in the code I can typical see method chaining like:

```java
return webClient.get()
  .uri(buildViewApiUrl(viewName, documents, dataSource, count, key))
  .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, bearerToken)
  .retrieve()
  .onStatus(status -> status.is4xxClientError() || status.is5xxServerError(), response -> 
     response.bodyToMono(KeepApiException.class)
       .flatMap(exception -> Mono.error(
           new KeepApiException(
             exception.getMessage(), exception.getErrorId(), exception.getErrorId()))))
  .bodyToMono(typeReference)
  .doOnError(throwable -> log.error("Failed to get data from view: " + viewName , throwable))
  .blockOptional()
  .orElse(null);
```

And I wonder *how could I inspect the object when going from one method to the next? How could I see which object is passed on to `.bodyToMono()`? or `.retrieve()`?* And so on.

In a similar example, `webClient.doA().doB().doC()`, I do understand I could do something similar to `A a  = webClient.doA(); ... inspect a ... ; Result = a.doB.doC()`, but is it possible to write a more generic debug method to just insert into the chain somehow?

Do note that in the first example, the types do change around in the chain, so splitting up the chain would be kind of a nuisance to type out with the proper types. So being able to do something like `.debug(a -> { System.out.println(a); return a })` would've been very nice.

I've seen answers like https://stackoverflow.com/a/41145698/1548472, where they're rebuilding the entire chain using `Optional`, and reckon that could possibly be an option. But my use case is that when I'm tracing down an issue I would like to insert/inspect at "random" places in various chains, so it would require a whole lot of code rewrite which I don't really want to do.

---

I've tried searching for an answer, but I've not found anything quite relevant (with the exception of the `Optional` answer I mentioned above), so maybe I'm using the wrong terms to search for or just fail to explain my use case. *In either case, I'm happy with any information pointing me in the right direction to be able to inspect what's being passed on in a "random" chain with minimal code insertion.*

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Whether it's an improvement is a matter of opinion. You don't need to write out any types.

```
package com.example.so;

import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Eg {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        D d = new A().doB().doC().doD();

        D d2 = debug(new A().doB(), b -> b.doC().doD(), b -> System.out.println(b));
    }

    public static <T, U> U debug(T t, Function<T, U> f, Consumer<T> inspect) {
        inspect.accept(t);
        return f.apply(t);
    }
}


class A {
    B doB() {
        return new B();
    }
}

class B {
    C doC() {
        return new C();
    }
}

class C {
    D doD() {
        return new D();
    }
}

class D {
}
```

Simply setting a breakpoint on one of the functions is an option too, if you are able to run under the debugger.

Comment: Sadly this suggestion would indeed require the massive code rewrite tag I'm trying to avoid. In most cases we can't use the debugger.